# How to best backup a server HDD to a secondary HDD

Tags: server, hard-drive, backup, rsync

I have a server with this configuration:

```
OS: Ubuntu server 16.04
HDD1: 1TB <system>
HDD2: 1TB <empty>
```

I would like to backup everything on HDD1 onto HDD2.
Ideally it would be a mirror image of the first drive and I would back things up either manually or on a schedule.
This is mainly for backup purposes not RAID.

I'm considering using `rsync` to backup the `/` directory.
But I'm unsure if that's a good idea.

What is the optimal way of backing up a drive like this?

Comment: Is your system installed to HDD1, is that what you mean by /root?  Or is that drive specifically mounted as your /root partition?  The later is easier.

Comment: @bc2946088 I meant it's a system drive. I changed it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rsync` will do the job.  It has the advantage of being able to boot from the backup drive and easily restore files with just a simple copy.  Conventional tools like `tar` and `dump` have the advantage of being able to compress the data so you can fit more incremental backups and go back further in time to restore a modified or deleted file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so let's say my main drive dies, I insert a new drive and then what do I do to recover the data with `rsync`? Do I need to install the operating system on the new drive and then copy the files or is there a way to just recover the drive or boot from the backup directly? Assuming I'm just dumping the `/` directory into the secondary drive.

Comment: @dcweaver01, you don't even need to install a new drive... you just need to install grub to the second drive, and when the first dies, just set your bios to boot from the second.